# Making unique index case-insensitive

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a unique index on the table and I need to make it case-insensitive, because I started getting duplicates in that table:

```
TEST
Test
TeSt
```

To fix the issue I was trying to drop existing index and re-create it:

```
 ALTER TABLE table1 drop constraint test_uk1;
 DROP INDEX test_uk1;
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_uk1 ON table1(UPPER(column1));

 ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT test_uk1 UNIQUE (column1) USING INDEX test_uk1 ENABLE VALIDATE;
```

I got an error `ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.` on the last statement.

Is there a better way to accomplish this with Oracle?

Comment: TEST <> Test <> TeSt in Oracle UNLESS you have messed with the COLLATE feature...how is your table defined or have you set this at the database level? https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2

Answer (score 4):

You can use a virtual column to normalise the case of the string and then put the unique constraint on the virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value  VARCHAR2(20),
  uvalue VARCHAR2(20)
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(value))
         CONSTRAINT table_name__uvalue__u UNIQUE
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES ('abc');
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES ('aBc');
```

Inserts one row and the second statement fails with:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_QDGWKZFBAWPLSRVHJNHN.TABLE_NAME__UVALUE__U) violated
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=779dc2f8045d12cb39a16ef1a5acd5f5)*

Answer (score 1):

You need not to `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT ...`, the definition of the *functional based index* is enough for the creation of the unique constraint.

It is also wrong, as you use `UNIQUE (column1)` which you *do not want*, so simple skip this statement.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_uk1 ON table1(UPPER(column1));

insert into table1 (column1) values('x');
insert into table1 (column1) values('X');

ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.TEST_UK1) violated
```

Answer (score 0):

Even independently of the DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Vertica, PostgreSQL, you name them), Indexes live and die with the fact that data is not modified/derived before the index or the optimisation taking advantage of the index is applied.

So your approach is doomed, as far as I can tell.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD column1_u DEFAULT UPPER(column1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_uk1 ON table1(column1_u);
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT test_uk1 UNIQUE(column1_u) 
 USING INDEX test_uk1 ENABLE VALIDATE;
```

I know, it's a long transaction if your table is big, as you need to shuffle half the tablespace, but it's worth it ..

Comment: *Your* approach of *"copying" the column*  is *doomed* (though often used), the *correct* way in recent Oracle is either functional based index or virtual column as posted in other answers.